# failure in make Prometheus: undefined sort.Slice

Tags: prometheus

I face with an error while building from source. Go version is:

```
> go version
go version go1.7.2 linux/amd64
```

The error is:

```
prometheus head.go undefined: sort.Slice
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prometheus needs to be compiled with go 1.8 I'm afraid.  `sort.Slice` was introduced in that version.